# Is performing a dynamic loop (from Variables) to create airflow tasks a good approach?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a simple airflow DAG with let's say 2 tasks. something like this:

```
newDirToLoad = Variable.get("path")
filesInDir = next(os.walk(newDirToLoad))[2] 

for f in filesInDir:
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id = "load_for_" + str(f),
        params = {"fileToProcess" : newDirToLoad + "/" + f}
        # ...
    )

    task1 = BashOperator(
        # ...
    )
    task1 >> task2
```

Here the *path* variable is initially set to some dummy directory so that my Dag wouldn't fail at Dag creation. 
Once a new directory with files are created under "data/to/load/" dir at some point, I have a script written somewhere which will trigger `airflow variables -set path data/to/load/$newDir` followed by `airflow trigger_dag myDag`. This works pretty well and i see number of tasks in airflow GUI is as same as the number of files present in $newDir. But i think its kind of a tweak to allow dynamic task creations using *Variable* feature. Are there any good approach? Is it a bad practice to initially set the path variable to some dummy directory for Dag's successful creation?

Comment: Looks fine to me since the entire dag and its dependencies are already defined prior to it being triggered. The approach that I don't like, and doesn't suit airflow very well, is when tasks are dynamically created based on outputs of other tasks within the same dag. A better approach however may be to make sure the files / directories where files land are named predictably and use airflow date macros to determine if there are any new ones?

Comment: but I'm not creating tasks dynamically based on other tasks, I'm creating it dynamically based on the variable changes + new trigger_dag

Comment: You might enjoy reading through a presentation that one of the Airflow commiters wrote: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVN4HXtOC-HXvv00sEkoB90mxLDnCIKc/view?usp=sharing

On slide 26 he recommends that DAGs should be slowly changing over time. While what you wrote will be functional, it could come with some operational headaches. You could benefit if there's a way to further separate your orchestration logic from execution.

Comment: @FaisalKhan I know. I was just mentioning what I don’t like as a seperate statement.

Comment: oh gotcha. I'll check it out @Chris. Thank you both 

Answer (score 0):

It's actually possible and very convenient.

I'd recommend you have a look at this blog post from the Astronomer's team: [Dynamically Generating DAGs in Airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/)

TL;DR you could write something like:

```py
customers = Variable.get("customers_list")
for customer in customers:
    dag = DAG(dag_id=f"dag_for_{customer}")

    run_first = DummyOperator(
        task_id='run_this_first',
        dag=dag
    )
    # for iteration purposes
    previous = run_first

    for step in Variable.get("customers_steps"):
        run_this = DummyOperator(
            task_id=f'run_{step}',
            dag=dag
        )
        previous >> run_this
        previous = run_this

    # From that point, the DAG is complete
    # Now, you need to put it in the module globals

    globals()[f"dag_for_{customer}"] = dag
```

This works because Airflow looks for DAG objects into the modules it's scanning. In that case, you would just have several DAGs into one module, which is perfectly fine.

Some pros and cons:

pros:

- The separation of concerns it offers can be very useful from a business standpoint. In the example of separating customers, you could eventually just edit the variable content and Airflow takes of generating / removing DAGs.
- For tasks, same thing
- The example uses variables because you asked for it but it can actually take whatever list you want, whereas it is a hardcoded one or a result of a query.

cons:

- keep in mind that you're generating DAGs at runtime and your module doesn't contain any static DAG. If you wish to import a DAG for some reason, you'd have to use some reflection in imports from another module but that seems to be a very rare case
- if your list is large, rebuilding the list of DAGs can be long. You would probably need to cut your DAGs in smaller ones and partition the list it's generating the DAGs from.
- if your DAGs change too much over time, you'll have a hard-time keeping relevant logs and it might be more difficult for the scheduler to track task triggering

Enjoy!